# How do you sort an array in PHP by key?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Here is my array, let's call it `$arr`

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [post] => 159 [city] => Denver [country] => [state] => Colorado) 
        [1] => Array ( [post] => 165 [city] => Miami [country] => United States [state] => Florida ) 
        [2] => Array ( [post] => 172 [city] => East Rutherford [country] => United States [state] => New Jersey ) )
```

I would like to sort this array by the key "city" in ascending order so the array will be:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [post] => 159 [city] => Denver [country] => [state] => Colorado) 
        [2] => Array ( [post] => 172 [city] => East Rutherford [country] => United States [state] => New Jersey )
        [1] => Array ( [post] => 165 [city] => Miami [country] => United States [state] => Florida ) )
```

I then want to also sort the array by the state key values in ascending order so it will look like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [post] => 159 [city] => Denver [country] => [state] => Colorado)
        [1] => Array ( [post] => 165 [city] => Miami [country] => United States [state] => Florida
        [2] => Array ( [post] => 172 [city] => East Rutherford [country] => United States [state] => New Jersey ) )
```

Comment: by the country name or key country..

Comment: actually sorry, I want to sort ascending by city key

Comment: I think you want to sort by the city value, since the array keys are all the same.

Comment: Ryan you are right, I'm an idiot, I want to sort by the city values and not keys, do you know how I can do that? I also want to sort by the state values.

Comment: Are you using a php5 feature?  You should remove that tag unless this question is specifically about something that is only in php5.

Comment: Check luissquall's link, example #3. The answer is right there.

Comment: A useful site comparing all php array sorting functions [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Comment: did you look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php ?

Comment: You should edit your existing questions rather than posting new ones.

Comment: // Sort the multidimensional array
     usort($array_posts, "custom_sort");
     // Define the custom sort function
     function custom_sort($a,$b) {
          return $a['city']>$b['city'];
     }

print_r($array_posts);

Comment: It seems that you getting results from database, why don't you consider put the sorting in SQL ?

Comment: Please don't repeat the same question over and over. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that solves your problem:

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    array("posts"=>323, "city"=>"london"),
    array("posts"=>223, "city"=>"birmingham"),
    array("posts"=>255, "city"=>"norwich"),
    array("posts"=>13, "city"=>"manchester"),
    array("posts"=>23, "city"=>"liverpool"),
);

function cmp($a, $b) 
{
        return ($a["posts"] >= $b["posts"]);
}


usort($arr, "cmp");

print_r($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use usort with a callback.

```
usort ($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return (strcmp ($a ['city'], $b ['city']));
});
```

anonymous functions only work since php 5.3 so in case you use something older move the callback to a new function:

```
function my_array_sort_callback($a, $b) {
    return (strcmp ($a ['city'], $b ['city']))
}

usort ($array, "my_array_sort_callback");
```

Comment: @Jeff'Digi'Lange: the anonymous function only works in php 5.3 and newer. You have to create a new function and use that (look at the usort documentation). I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Example #3 of array_multisort: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Answer (score 0):

First store the array in a variable then run the loop

```
$fruits = array("d"=>"lemon", "a"=>"orange", "b"=>"banana", "c"=>"apple");
ksort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```

The output will be
    a = orange
    b = banana
    c = apple
    d = lemon

Comment: That's not making any sense to me when you switch it to a complete different array.  I want to use the array I have and sort it by the city key in ascending order...

Comment: But this is not letting me sort by the city key or the state key.  I want to be able to sort by the keys.

Answer (score 0):

try this, suppose if $arr is your array than

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$v):
ksort($v);
endforeach;

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: But this is not letting me sort by the city key or the state key.  I want to be able to sort by the keys.

Comment: but ksort sorts your array by keys., can you give me some more about what exaclty you want.

Comment: punit - I got the above array you see in the example. I want to be able to display results for having the array sorted by using the KEY "city" than I want to be able to sort by the KEY "state".

Comment: Correction, I'm an idiot, I want to sort by the CITY values not key. And the same for state values.

Comment: If I sorted them by city values then the results would be:
Array ( 
 [2] => Array ( [post] => 172 [city] => East Rutherford [country] => United States [state] => New Jersey
[0] => Array ( [post] => 159 [city] => Miami [country] => [state] => Florida ) 
        [1] => Array ( [post] => 165 [city] => Miami [country] => United States [state] => Florida ) 
        ) )

Answer (score 0):

I would say the answer is in http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php